# Create temporary table

Tags: oracle11g

I'm coming from SQL Server enviroment where you can declare a temp table with @table, but as I've read you can't do this in oracle.

I want get a value for 500.000 hardcoded id's from a table, but as the IN clause has a limit of 1000 I need to find another way. Is the best way to create a temporary table and insert the hardcoded values and then join the other table which contains the values I need ?

My client (toad) has autocommit set to off and I dont want to commit anything, I want it to be session-based so when I close the database client I want the temporary table do disappear. Is the code below the right way to do in oracle?

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Test(HardcodedId number(10))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

I've also tried to use inner join and in the join select the hardcoded values from dual, but this creates a column for each value and i'm not able to use a reference to join with. Is it possible to insert all values into a single column in dual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some thing like this (500 union all)

```
select * from (
select '1' from dual
union all
select '2' from dual
...) q
```

Then you can join this with other tables.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How will the performance be by doing this for 500.000 values ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the performance to be that great because that'd be a huge statement for the database to have to parse. For an ad-hoc thing, I would probably use a combination of the union all's and ins, eg. `select ... from ... where id in (<list of 1st 1000 ids) union all select ... from ... where id in (<list of 2nd 1000 ids) union all ...`

Answer (score 1):

For your situation, I would use a GTT (global temporary table) - which you have already researched by the looks.

The advantage of a GTT is that it's a permanent object (so no need to constantly create and drop it) and the data "stored" in it is on a session basis.

Comment: Will the temporary table be deleted when i close the database client or do i need to make a commit before it get's deleted ?

Comment: the temporary table will remain, but the data will be deleted a) when a commit/rollback is actioned, b) the session is closed, c) when you issue a manual `delete from gtt` statement or d) when you do a truncate of the gtt (but beware of the implicit commit, because this is a DDL command).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will be in production enviroment, so i dont want to add a table to the db.

Comment: Is this an ad-hoc thing then, rather than something that will be run regularly as production code?

Comment: Ah right, for something ad-hoc, I agree that you probably don't want to be creating tables in prod! *{;-)